# Hibernate UnsatisfiedDependencyException : Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting the

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Following is my Friendship entity class

```
// Friendship.java

package com.socialPulse.socialPulse.modal;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "friendship")
public class Friendship {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id", nullable = false)
    private User friend;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters

    public Friendship() {
    }

    public Friendship(User user, User friend, String status) {
        this.user = user;
        this.friend = friend;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getFriend() {
        return friend;
    }

    public void setFriend(User friend) {
        this.friend = friend;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Following is my Friendship Repositry

```
@Query("SELECT f.friend_id FROM Friendship f WHERE f.user_id = :userId")
List<Long> findFriendIdsByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

i'm getting exception for `findFriendIdsByUserId` this method . I'm not sure the query looks correct to me , which would fetch friendIds from table where userID matches with the param i'm sending.

My Friendship table schema looks likes

```
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS friendship (`
`id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,`
`user_id BIGINT,`
`friend_id BIGINT,`
`status VARCHAR(255),`
`CONSTRAINT unique_user_friend UNIQUE (user_id, friend_id),`
`FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_table(id),`
`FOREIGN KEY (friend_id) REFERENCES user_table(id)`
`);`
```

when i try to run the query (`SELECT f.friend_id FROM friendship f WHERE f.user_id = 1`) in my DB i'm getting the output as :

```
friend_id  
2
3
4
```

where my Friendship table looks like

```
id      user_id     friend_id   status  
1      1              2        accepted
3      1              3        accepted
4      1              4        accepted
```

Tried debugging & going through other stackoverflow answers but no luck. Expecting someone to help .

Comment: Can you please share the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Your query is a mixture of JPQL and SQL that will not work, decide what to use. With JPQL you should write something like this. `SELECT f.friend.id FROM Friendship f WHERE f.user.id = :userId`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you it worked. I was not aware to use friend.id for column name friend_id in JPQL .

Comment: It is **not** a column name you provide it is the object paths you define in JPQL. You are navigating objects not database fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing JPQL and native SQL in your query.

Use either this for native SQL:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT f.friend_id FROM friendship f WHERE f.user_id = :userId", nativeQuery = true)
```

or this for JPQL:

```java
@Query("SELECT f.friend.id FROM Friendship f WHERE f.user.id = :userId")
```

Comment: Thank you . 
Slight correction , adding value attribute before query

@Query(value = "SELECT f.friend_id FROM friendship f WHERE f.user_id = :userId", nativeQuery = true)